# Biztalk AS2 MDN AS2EdiReceive "No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data"

Tags: biztalk, response, message, actionscript-2

Okay, I've looked through all the walkthroughs on the MSDN.. and I don't know what's happening.  I've got an asynchronous MDN that's being received by my  One-Way port which has the pipeline as "AS2EdiReceive".

All EDI files come in fine.  It's the MDN files that generate the "No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data".  Here's the exact error:

`There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "EDI disassembler" Receive Port: "prtMicroEDIRCV" URI: "/sorocmicrous/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" Reason: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data`.

If I check the message context, the IsAS2MdnResponseMessage = True.  So It obviously knows it's an MDN.  I can't figure out how to get this MDN past this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I found the answer.  and it was on this web page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb728190(v=BTS.20).aspx

And in the second paragraph it says:

> However, if you use AS2EdiReceive, you
>   cannot route the MDN into the
>   MessageBox by setting the "Process
>   inbound MDN into MessageBox for
>   routing/delivery options" property
>   (for the party as AS2 message
>   receiver). Trying to do so will result
>   in an EDI error because the MSN will
>   be passed to the EDI Decoder, which
>   cannot process an MDN. If the MDN is
>   not sent to the MessageBox, the
>   AS2Decoder will consume the MDN, so it
>   will not be passed to the EDI Decoder.

I'm monitoring it now, but it seems to have done the job.